# sublime Text - how to go to end of multiple lines when they have different length

Tags: sublimetext

After select all rows, I want to go to eol for all lines. It used to work with command + right arrow, but somehow it doesn't work with new mac.
lines example:

```
Bill_Apple;;Denver_CO
Colin_James;;Fulton_CA
Franklin_Rose;;Seattle_WA
```

What I had added to blindings

```
[
{ “keys”: [“command+left”], “command”: “move_to”, “args”: {“to”: “hardbol”, “extend”: false} },
{ “keys”: [“command+right”], “command”: “move_to”, “args”: {“to”: “hardeol”, “extend”: false} }
]
```

logs

```
command: drag_select {“event”: {“button”: 1, “x”: 398.1328125, “y”: 37.734375}}
command: select_lines {“forward”: true}
command: select_lines {“forward”: true}
command: move_to {“extend”: false, “to”: “hardeol”}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to use [multiple cursors](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/multiple_selection_with_the_keyboard.html). You don't need to add any keybindings, and in fact, you probably shouldn't. It's always best to leave the default settings intact if at all possible. To get a cursor at the end of every line, use these steps:

1. Select All (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) or use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+arrows or the mouse to select your lines
2. Split the selection into lines (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)
3. Move all cursors to the end of their respective lines (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd>)